# Php Check if 2 from Database are empty

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, exists

Hello I am working on simple video script where I need to do the following:

I need to check if Variable **Source** is empty (if it's not empty echo $source, but if it is empty proceed to check other variable below)

if Variable **Embed** is set, if it is set (echo $embed), but if it is empty do

echo $image

Basically I have setup system for Videos that can load either from Youtube Video with iframe, either with Embed from all kinds of other pages

but if Both of this fields are empty I need to show just image that will be set from URL

Comment: `if(isset($var)){ echo 'yes it is set'; }`
`if(!isset($var)){ echo 'no it is not set'; }`

Comment: Yes but this way, it will show up for example:

It will show Source and Image because Image is always set, I wan to show image only if 2 other fields are not set

Comment: What i like to do in this kind of instance is preset the variable as something else.  For example.  At the very top of your php page, set `$embed = 0;`

Then in your scripts, you will be re declaring $embed.
Then when you run your script, instead of sayin if isset, say `if($embed != 0)`.  If you did not redeclare $embed, it will still equal 0, but if you did, the script will run.

Comment: When declared Source equals YoutubeVideoUrl or it's simply empty

When Declared Embed equals EMBEDCODE or it's simply empty

Image will be SET for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an elseif-statement.

```
if(isset($source) && $source) {
    echo $source;
} elseif(isset($embed) && $embed) {
    echo $embed;
} else {
    echo $image;
}
```